# Typecasting a Dataframe returns 'null' for empty fields

Tags: scala, dataframe, hive, null, apache-spark-sql

I have a raw data loaded into my hive tables with all the columns as strings by default. Now I need to change the datatypes of hive tables to export to SQLServer.
When Typecasting the hive columns the empty fields returns 'NULL', tried loading the hive tables into dataframe and typecast the columns, but still dataframe also returning 'null' for empty fields. SQLserver couldn't recognize such values.

Can anyone suggest a solution to avoid the 'null' values in display when I get data from hive or dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the data type only because you want to have that particular format in exported data, consider using writing to a directory as per your requirement and then export using sqoop/any other tool.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '<HDFS path>'
Row format delimited
Fields terminated by '<delimiter>'
SELECT
a,
b
From
table_name
Where <condition>;
```

While exporting, if you have null values consider using these arguments in your sqoop command

```
--null-string "\\N" --null-non-string "\\N"
```

Hope this helps you